# How easy is it to fit a garage door opener?

Tags: electrical, garage-door-opener

My wife is desperate to have a garage door opener, and she's found [this kit](http://www.diy.com/nav/build/doors-windows/doors/garage-doors/garage_door_openers__frames___accessories/Tormatic-Garage-Door-Remote-Control-System-GD700-11927501) at B&Q. Can anyone advise on how easy/straightforward these things are to install? It'll be me (and most likely my Dad) installing it, and I think between us we're *reasonably* capable, but I haven't done anything of this kind of scale before, and I imagine if it comes down and whacks my wife's new car it'll be my fault...

Also, regarding the electrics is it something I need an electrician to come and wire up for me? I have two fluorescent tubes in the garage ceiling, but I'm guessing if I run a spur from them down to the GDO, we'll need to leave the lights on all the time? (I'm in the UK if that makes a difference)

Comment: Make sure you check all of the clearances.  If you don't have the clearance then you start getting into special track kits, modifying parts of your garage, etc. which significantly complicates the job.

Answer (score 3):

If you're not comfortable with running electricity in a safe manner, then yes, you should have an electrician install an outlet in the ceiling near where you intend to install the opener.  You can run a split off the line that feeds the lights, but you do need to run the opener on an always-on circuit, so you have to know what you're doing there.

As for the installation itself, as long as you're reasonably handy, know how to find proper structural supports (ie: the framing), the installation should not be very difficult.  Obviously the install will vary based on the model but generally you'll install a mounting brace of some kind, which needs to be VERY securely attached to the structure of your garage (not just the drywall - but INTO the joists/studs).  The rest should be pretty simple as long as you read the directions carefully and plan it all out before you actually start.

Comment: just out of interest from your answer. It is legal to have a power outlet run from a light circuit?

Comment: That's a good question.  I'm so used to working on 1940's built homes where lights and outlets are all on the same circuit, I don't know if the newer codes allow it or not.

Answer (score 0):

Fairly simple to install if you follow the instructions. Just make sure the unit is securely fixed to a solid mount not just to the plaster. Sometimes it can be a bit tricky if the headroom above the door is very limited. As far as the electrical slide I'm not an electrician but running a gpo of a light circuit is a defiant no no in Australia. Maybe someone with electrical background could clarify this for uk?

Answer (score 0):

I've installed two garage door openers in my time; the first one was installed immediately after I moved into my new house at age 24, and was one of the first  home improvement projects I ever did.

I did have the advantage of already having an outlet there; As others have said, you'll need to have either an electrician or a handy friend run the wire.  Garages are usually pretty easy to wire as the cables and whatnot are usually accessible.